# A tricky concatenation of strings

Tags: python, string, selenium, string-concatenation

I have to format a string to be in a specific form, but unfortunately all my attempts have failed..

```
# What I want:
//*[@id="ember205"]

# What I am getting:
//*[@id=ember205]

# Additional details, where I need it and the way I am constructing it:
moveToStep = str("ember"+str(int(199)+int(step_number * 3)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="+moveToStep+"]").click()
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="'+moveToStep+'"]').click()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining strings with + usually isn't the best idea, python has a couple of ways to [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```py
moveToStep = 199 + step_number * 3
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember{}"]'.format(moveToStep)).click()
```

or on Python 3.6+ you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#examples-from-python-s-source-code)

```py
moveToStep = 199 + step_number * 3
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="ember{moveToStep}"]').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [.format()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)?

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"{0}\"]".format(moveToStep)).click()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added more context or a link to explain it. I'll know for next time :)